# Splitting the big Array into small parts with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, split

I need to split below array into three arrays:
The result of tc_excel variable

```
[(1000000, ['FA'], 'bev.xml'),
 (1001001, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1003000, ['FA'], 'phev.xml'),
 (1003001, ['TC', 'CT01', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1003002, ['TC', 'CT01', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1004000, ['FA'], 'tesla.xml'),
 (1004001, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1004002, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False)]
```

- One array should be all the Testcases with xml that have "bev" in the name of file
- the array two should have phev in the name of xml file
- the rest should be all other cases

All splitted array should have a minimumt one ['FA'] Number one from these,(
`['1000000,'1003000,'1004000]`

```
def testcasefilter(tc_input, tc_max, config_reiter, excel_pfad):
    if abs(tc_max) < 2:
        return []

    if not os.path.isfile(excel_pfad):
        return []

    tc_excel = get_fnt_testcases(excel_pfad, config_reiter)
    intervalls, kats, notkats = decode_tc_selection(tc_input)
    print tc_excel
    
    tc_excel_ok = []
    tc_codierung_ok = []

    for id_, katlist, cod in tc_excel:
        for kat in katlist:
            if kat in kats:
                tc_excel_ok.append(id_)
                if cod:
                    tc_codierung_ok.append(id_)
                break
            elif notkats and kat not in notkats:
                tc_excel_ok.append(id_)
                if cod:
                    tc_codierung_ok.append(id_)
                break
        else:
            if notkats and not katlist:
                tc_excel_ok.append(id_)
                if cod:
                    tc_codierung_ok.append(id_)
            elif check_tc_spec(id_, intervalls):
                tc_excel_ok.append(id_)
                if cod:
                    tc_codierung_ok.append(id_)

    temp_out = []
    cod = None
    temp = []
    if tc_max < 0:
        tc_max = len(tc_excel_ok) / abs(tc_max) + 2  # +1 Extra-Kodiertestcase +1 Rundung
        if tc_max < 2:
            return []

    for tc in tc_excel_ok:
        if len(temp) < tc_max:
            temp.append(tc)
            if tc in tc_codierung_ok:
                cod = tc
        else:
            temp_out.append(temp)
            temp = [tc]
            if tc in tc_codierung_ok:
                cod = tc
            elif cod is not None:
                temp = [cod, tc]
    temp_out.append(temp)

    output = []
    for elem in temp_out:
        o = ""
        for e in elem:
            o += str(e) + ";"
        output.append(o[:-1])
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print testcasefilter("*", 3, "Konfiguration", r"C:\Data\DSPLIT.xlsx")
```

The result output should be like becasuse we have one pev one phev and the third xml is not bev or not phev
['1000000;1001001','1003000;1003001;1003002','1004000;1004001;1004002']

Comment: Which field is the CODE?  I don't see phev anywhere.  I see bev inside of a string in the third array.  The output format makes no sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake one ['FA'] should be like this pfgs_phev.xml. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Which one of the 3 FAs should be like that?  You still haven't said which field is CODE.  And your "this is what should be" does not match your description.  For example why should 1001001 be grouped with 1000000 when one has a bev and the other does not?

Comment: In general step 1 in programming is thinking clearly about why you are doing what you are doing.  Step 2 is being able to say what you want to do clearly.  Step 3 is figuring out how to tell the computer to do what you want.  Right now we're on step 2 but it is a muddle.  Without a clear understanding of what we want done, we have no hope of telling a computer to do it.

Comment: So every TCs (Testcase) should have only one FA thats why 1000000 (FA);1001001' (TC) are group together. The number of TC and FA ist ascending This is another group because is another FA 1003000 xml File is diffrent. So i have edited also the question. I hope the situation is clear to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
test = [(1000000, ['FA'], 'bev.xml'),
 (1001001, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1003000, ['FA'], 'phev.xml'),
 (1003001, ['TC', 'CT01', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1003002, ['TC', 'CT01', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1004000, ['FA'], 'tesla.xml'),
 (1004001, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False),
 (1004002, ['TC', 'CT03', 'CT04'], False)]

bev = [1003000]
notbev = [1000000,100400]
arrayall = [1000000,1001001,1003000,1003001,1003002,1004000,1004001,1004002]
arr_part_bev = []
arr_part_not_bev = []
isbev = False
for i in arrayall:
  if i in bev:
    arr_part_bev.append(i)
    isbev = True
  elif i in notbev:
    arr_part_not_bev.append(i)
    isbev = False  
  else:
    if isbev:
      arr_part_bev.append(i)
    else :
      arr_part_not_bev.append(i)

print (arr_part_bev)
print (arr_part_not_bev)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save my day!